# Reversing Java For Loop

Tags: java

I have this code, which I am trying to print the following shape out...

```
****
* *
**
*
```

Current Code:

```
  System.out.print("\nEnter number of rows: ");
  rows = kybd.nextInt();
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      System.out.print("*");
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
          if (j == 1 || j == rows - 1 || j == i) {
              System.out.print("*");
          } else {
              System.out.print("0");
          }
      }
      System.out.println();
  }
```

For some reason, it prints out like this:

```
****
*
**
* *
```

Any idea how to reverse the second for loop, so it prints the other way?

Comment: _For some reason_...You want us to find the reason because you don't know how to debug?

Comment: How does `System.out.print("0")` come into this?

Comment: You want `for (int i = rows - 1; i > 0 ; i--)`.  And you want to go and read all about `for` loops before you go too much further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel you should change your `i` loop

```
for (int i = rows - 1; i > 0 ; i--)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("\nEnter number of rows: ");
    int rows = kybd.nextInt();

    if (rows > 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            System.out.print("*");
        System.out.println();

        for (int i = rows - 1; i > 1; i--) {
            System.out.print("*");
            for (int j = 2; j < i; j++)
                System.out.print(" ");
            System.out.println("*");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("*");
```

Sample output:

```
Enter number of rows: 6
******
*   *
*  *
* *
**
*
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice, that you are printing out the first line of asterisk in a separate cycle, not inside the main one. If you want to follow this road, you need to put the first cycle behind the second one.

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        if ((j == 1) || (j == (rows - 1)) || (j == i)) {
            System.out.print("*");
        } else {
            System.out.print("0");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    System.out.print("*");
}
```

Comment: (Although I think the "correct solution" wrt. an assignment might be to merge the loop logic, this does explain the behavior.)

Comment: This does not do what the OP requires.  -1.

Comment: @DavidWallace This answer correctly explains the problem - it *cannot* be addressed with just fixing the 2nd loop (excluding terminal magic) - and presents a solution. While I don't think it's a "correct for class" solution, that is now back on the OP.

Comment: OP needs to fix his problem, but hey, your call :)